# Karate retry for SQL query

Tags: karate

I need to validate SQL query until SQL query populates the results,
Here is the implementation looks like
e.g

```
        Given path 'abc'
        And request Requestbody
        And method Post
        Then status 201
        And retry until dbr.type == 'xyz'
        * print dbr.type
        * sleep(100000)
        * def dbr = db.readRows("SELECT job.type from job where job.entity = '123456' AND job.type = 'xyz'")
        * print dbr
```

Our system is going to populate a result after 10-30sec, so i need to validate by using the retry for Sql query,
Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

The `retry until` syntax is only for HTTP calls and dealing with the `response`.

For this use-case, you should use a custom polling routine - you can get an idea here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#polling

Since you are writing Java code to do the SQL query, the best thing (in my opinion) is to do this polling in the Java code itself, it will be much simpler.